# What is love actually?

Tags: love, relations

Okayyy.. this can be a bit long but if you can give satisfactory ANSWER to it... it might be very helpful to me... so the situation about me is....

1. How do you come to know if you are in love?
2. You are not sure that if you are in love or not (look the person's soul(my friend) is pure, but we think a bit differently at some points/aspects of life) and due to this.. neither you are accepting their proposals or whatever it is... nor you are saying them that you love them (cause you aren't sure, and thus you don't want to play with their feelings), and they are waiting for you to say it cause they have already said it.
3. There is something you find good to talk, to chat, to spend time with them. A one message from them can change your mood from sad to happy. And if you don't talk to them for some days(2-3), it feels like you have missed a lot of something very big part of your life. You wait (in your leisure or sometimes while doing your routine work) for your night conversations to happen, the whole day. BUT STILL, you don't see them as your future spouse for some unknown reasons.. it might be cause you both are very good at friends level, but some unknown dots seems to be missing due to which you don't take them as your spouse(idk what are those reasons exactly), but friends for the whole life ( I know this friends for the whole life situations will change at some point of them life, but this is what it is.. ) It might also be possible in future that they fall for someone else and will forget/leave you, although they feel the same for you(atleast at current moment of life or even want to you more than you want them), but still.. TILL WHEN someone would wait for you, haha!

Why there is so much of confusion? Why you don't see them as your future spouse if you are in love? Or you are just not in love? And if the situation I told you above is not love, then what it is? And if you are not in love.. then what it is to be in love, how does it feel?

Comment: "Love" is not like a city, strictly speaking you are not *in* love. Statement "We/I are in love" is used to characterise/tag a particular state of relationship. That state of relationship has "operational" existence, it is less of a concept, more of an engineering issue. Love is, therefore, not a destination, but a journey.

Comment: @Ajax Thanks for your words that I am not in love, but I am still not clear what it is actually! You said "this is not a destination, but a journey".... . It actually seems to be a bookish language. Would be helpful if you can explain it or tell a bit more, or if you have experienced it and can tell something based on it... Suppose you are telling it to a machine (with no emotions)

Comment: @Ajax *"'Love' is not like a city"* [Are you sure?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Love,_Saskatchewan)

Comment: @Weirdoooo Two couples may have same relationship, but one couple may characterise being in love, while other may not. Love is mostly subjective, and also has a social element attached to it (security, reciprocity, ...). Would you say, "We are in love, but I obviously don't expect him/her to help me out in any kind" ?  You can feel infatuation, sexual attraction, appreciation, respect or care towards a person independently. You may feel some or all of it and declare I'm in love, or feel all of it and still say, "I'm not in love." Love is not a declaration, it is *built*.

Answer (score 1):

If you are being sincere when you say "you don't see them as your future spouse for some unknown reasons" perhaps you should see a therapist to figure out what those reasons are and if they are good reasons.

Love is more than a feeling. Love is a kindly action in response to a shared connection or to a lack of a shared connection.

Comment: sure,I would try finding therapist about this haha, You are saying that "Love is a kindly......connection",like being kind human, one is kind to everyone if that person is stranger(in my case), moreover we do kind actions to our family members and friends, but how do you actually feel that you are in love?( It sometimes seems like I'm a robot with 0 emotions that I gotta post such questions here instead of getting emotions on my own,LOL). I've read a lot of stuff on the internet about this on internet but was still confused about my case(not getting it). Elaboration would be helpful.

Comment: Dr. Gabor Mate on attachment and authenticity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l3bynimi8HQ

Comment: Dr. Tori Olds explains what trauma is. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tKc4o_Faej8

Answer (score 0):

> "Subtle degrees
>
> of domination and servitude
>
> are what you know as love

> but love is different
>
> it arrives complete
>
> just there
>
> like the moon in the window

> like the sun
>
> of neither east nor west
>
> nor of any place

> when that sun arrives
>
> east and west arrive

> desire only that
>
> of which you have no hope
>
> seek only that
>
> of which you have no clue

> love is the sea of not-being
>
> and there intellect drowns

> this is not the Oxus River
>
> or some little creek
>
> this is the shoreless sea;
>
> here swimming ends
>
> always in drowning

> a journey to the sea
>
> is horses and fodder
>
> and contrivance
>
> but at land’s end
>
> the footsteps vanish

> you lift up your robe
>
> so as not to wet the hem;
>
> come! drown in this sea
>
> a thousand times

> the moon passes over
>
> the ocean of non-being

> droplets of spray tear loose
>
> and fall back
>
> on the cresting waves

> a million galaxies
>
> are a little scum
>
> on that shoreless sea."

> -Rumi